# How to freeze left column in matrix rendered as a container in JS/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, r, matrix, shiny

I'm trying to freeze the left-most column of the matrix rendered as a container via JS/CSS, as shown in the image below. I believe the issue lies with the line `runjs("$('#container').scrollLeft(1000)")` towards the bottom of the code. I keep fiddling with this line with no luck, as my JS/CSS skills are lacking. Any recommendations for solving this?

[image]

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

mat3Rows <- c('Term A','Term B','Term C','Term D')

mat3Default <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1, 24, 0, 100), row.names = mat3Rows) %>% as.matrix()

mat3Input <- function(inputId, mat3Default) {
  matrixInput(
    inputId = inputId,
    label = "Input terms:",
    value = mat3Default,
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE, delete = TRUE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(style = "margin-top: 20px"),
  actionButton('modMat3','Modify')
  )

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  rv3        <- reactiveValues( 
    mat3      = mat3Input("mat3",mat3Default),
    input     = mat3Default,
    colHeader = colnames(input)
  ) 
  
  mat3Inputs <- reactive({
    df <- mat3Default
    colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:ncol(df)) 
    df[3:4, ] <- sprintf('%.2f%%', df[3:4, ]) 
    df
  })

  observeEvent(input$modMat3, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      wellPanel(div(style = "overflow-x: auto;", id = "container",rv3$mat3)), 
      footer = tagList(modalButton("Close"))
      ) 
    ) 
  }) 
  
  # Prevents input matrix 3 from scrunching as it expands
  observeEvent(c(input$modMat3, input$mat3), {
    print(paste0('$("#mat3").css("width","calc(100% + ', (dim(input$mat3)[2]-1 + dim(input$mat3)[2]%%2)*115, 'px")'))
    runjs(paste0('$("#mat3").css("width","calc(100% + ', (dim(input$mat3)[2]-1 + dim(input$mat3)[2]%%2)*115, 'px")'))
    runjs("$('#container').scrollLeft(1000)") # solution will be in this line
  })

}) 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: hello, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky simple test : https://jsfiddle.net/abw4q5s3/